# Separate angularjs library from bundled browserify

Tags: angularjs, browserify

I've got a gulp task that browersify my files. currently it works by bundling everything including the angular.js file which is quite large. I want to pull angular.js out and load that in my index.html just before the bundled javascript file.

I've done this by adding the .external('angular') to the browserify call but the bundled resulting file does not get any smaller, and when I run the app in a browser, it acts like it is still trying to load the node angular package (error: Uncaught Error: Cannot find module 'angular')

Below is my gulp task that is where the problem is I believe.

```
function identity (input) {
  return input;
}

function bundler (watch, mocks) {
  var b = (watch ? watchify : identity)(
      browserify(watch && watchify.args)
      .external('angular')
  );
  b.add(format('./%s', app)).add('babel/polyfill');
  if (mocks) b.add(format('./%s/mock', app));
  return b;
}

function bundle (bundler) {
  return bundler
    .bundle()
    .pipe(source('main.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/app'));
}

gulp.task('bundle', function () {
  var bundled = bundle(bundler())
  if (!production) return bundled;
  return bundled
    .pipe(buffer())
      .pipe(replace(/('|")use strict\1/g, ''))
    .pipe(plugins.uglify())
    .pipe(plugins.rename({
      suffix: '.min'
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/app'));
});
```